# JGit Flow plugin stops after entering passphrase

Tags: bash, intellij-idea, git-bash, jgitflow-maven-plugin

I use JGitFlow-Plugin in my project (https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jgit-flow/wiki/Home). The authorization for the Git repository is based on ssh.

When calling for example jgitflow:release-start, I am asked to enter my passphrase for my key (btw. enableSshAgent is set to true, of course). After entering my passphrase, the process does not go on (it still waits for an input although I did)

I can see that behavior using Git Bash on Windows and also when using the internal Terminal in IntelliJ. using Windows powershell everything works fine.

Does anybody know why that does not really work using Git-Bash? Is there any configuration I have to set or activate?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the environment where you are trying to use JGit.
It looks like your PowerShell environment is different from the one which you have in Git Bash on Windows and its IDE, so if you start your cmd.exe from PowerShell it should work.

Comment: Great idea, but when I start IntelliJ idea from Powershell and try to run the JGitFlow plugin from the maven plugin window, it does not work